# Create a tree-structured graph from a csv

Tags: python, graph, treeview

I have the following csv file(below is a sample) and I want to generate a sitemap using python:

> title,url,id,parentid
>   'HomePage','www.example.com','1111','0000'
>   'FirstPage','www.example.com/firstpage','2222','1111'
>   'SecondPage','www.example.com/secondpage','3333','1111'

I believe a tree-like graph is the most suitable. There is a one-to-many relationship. A site can have multiple subsites but only belongs to a single one. I am looking for a simple python library to achieve this as I am not very experience with graphs. 
[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have following CSV file:

> title,url,id,parentid
>   HomePage,www.example.com,1111,0000
>   FirstPage,www.example.com/firstpage,2222,1111
>   SecondPage,www.example.com/secondpage,3333,1111

Run this script against CSV file:

```
import csv
from anytree import Node
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter

nodes = {}
with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        name = '{}\n{}'.format(row[0], row[1])
        node_id = row[2]
        parent_id = row[3]
        if i == 0:
            node = Node(name)  # root node
        else:
            node = Node(name, nodes[parent_id])
        nodes[node_id] = node

DotExporter(nodes[next(iter(nodes))]).to_picture('tree.png')  # graphviz required
```

And you'll get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Beside Tree, python graph module *networkx* could be used to depict it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import csv
G=nx.DiGraph()
lables = {}
edge=[]
with open('test.csv') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     next(reader)  # skip the first line in the input file
     for i,row in enumerate(reader):
         print(row)
         lables[row[2]] = row[0]
         if i!= 0:
            edge.append((row[2],row[3]))
G.add_edges_from(edge)
# positions for all nodes
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,node_size=1000)
# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, with_labels = False ,width=6)
# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos,lables,font_size=16)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: site map]